# Media Player gone on front end

Tags: media, audio

This seems to have happened since the WordPress 4.0 upgrade (I think). When I use the "Add Media" button for an audio file, I can see the player in the WP backend, and it functions. But it doesn't show up on the page at all. I noticed this with a couple plugins that call the built-in media player, but in testing, it doesn't work even with a simple insert, as noted.

I do have another site (on different server, mind you) running WP 3.9.2 where the media player is working fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check for javascript errors in other scripts (via the console) which might prevent the mediaelement stuff from running.

Comment: Thanks, bonger. Rather don't think that's the problem, since both sites had operating media players until very recently, and I didn't add anything to either of them. The only common factor I can think of is the 4.0 upgrade.

Comment: well did you check for javascript errors anyway?

Comment: Sounds like a javascript problem. Does it work on the default theme without any plugins? I wonder if this question is too localized?

Comment: There are no javascript errors, at least not on the live pages.

Comment: If you inspect the html source, is the `<audio>` element there but with style set to `visibility: hidden` ? If so then check that "wp-mediaelement" ("wp-includes/js/mediaelement/wp-mediaelement.js") is loaded. If so then put a breakpoint on line 31 where it calls `mediaelementplayer()` and see if it's reached.

Comment: Thanks, bonger. Yup, it's got visibility:hidden in there, which is odd, since it showed until very recently. Could you explain what you mean by setting a breakpoint (I'm assuming you're referring to the wp-mediaelement.js file)? I do lots of stuff with WordPress, but I'm about 0.5 out of 10 on javascript.

Comment: Well, that led me to a CSS "solution" (i.e. not sure if it's the "right" way, but it works): I threw .wp-audio-shortcode { visibility:visible !important; } at the end of my style.css file, and the audio player showed up again. Is there a downside to that, i.e. am I papering over a bigger issue?

Comment: Well it's just using the native HTML5 audio element now, rather than the mediaelement stuff, so yes, you are papering over! To begin js debugging, you right click the page and choose "Inspect Element (Q)" (Firefox) and first click the "Console" tab, check that "JS" logging is set & reload the page to see if any errors are reported. If not then click the "Debugging" tab and scroll thru the sources to find "wp-mediaelement.js" and (if it's there) click on line 31 to set a breakpoint and reload again.

Comment: Can't get Console to work. Get this message: "Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

Comment: Tabbing over to the Debugger, I don't see wp-mediaelement.js in the list of Sources.

Comment: A quick google indicates that that message might be Facebook related (invalid appid or something) - is it coming up as an error (in red) and do you use a FB plugin? If so try disabling it. However you should still see "wp-mediaelement.js" in the sources I think - try searching for "wp-media" in the debugger search box...